Flutter singlechildscrollview layout error
I coded simple screen like below.
However singlechildscollview column hide upper +/- button.
Why this symptoms occured? and how can I fix it?

my development condition as follows

android : 2024.1.1
flutter :
Flutter 3.22.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 761747bfc5 (5 weeks ago) • 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
Engine • revision edd8546116
Tools • Dart 3.4.3 • DevTools 2.34.3
mobile phone : z-flip3, version 14

PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: _customPopFunction,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  ButtonSpamMain(addOrNOt: true, onTap: _tabTopButtonHandler,),
                  ButtonSpamMain(addOrNOt: false, onTap: _tabTopButtonHandler,),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: Container(height: 70, color: Colors.grey, child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      showSpamList ? "스팸 처리된 목록" : "현재 메시지 목록", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),),)
                ],
              ),
              Text(_smsMessage),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      ...List.generate(((_messages.length) > 10 ?
                          intShowMessageNumber * 10
                          : _messages.length) ,
                              (index) {
                                var message = _messages[index];
                                return ListMessage(
                                  address: message['address'],
                                  body: message['body'],
                                  date: _formatDate(message['date']),
                                  id: message['id'],
                                  showCheckOrNot: showCheckOrNot,
                                  selected: _selectedIds.contains(message['id']) ,
                                  onTap: () => showCheckOrNot ?
                                    _tabListTrueHandler(message['id'])
                                    : _tabListFalseHandler(message['address'], message['body'], _formatDate(message['date'])),
                                  onLongPress: _longPressListHandler,
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline, size: 30,),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            intShowMessageNumber++;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20,)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                        color: showSpamList ? GREEN_BBDD : RED_FA9B,
                      ),
                      height: 120,
                      child: Center(child: Text(showSpamList ? '스팸 설정하기' : '스팸 취소하기', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

I just want to work as normal singlechildscrollview.
Upper buttons shall not be hided that.

use stack and wrap the column (whose children widgets should be scrollable) using SingleChildScrollView . wrap those buttons inside Positioned widget( set these properites top:0 ,left:0 , right:0 ). try it in this way.

Thank you for reply
Actually i got there are some issue for rendering of Ink widget
